# Php Array, cycle through a 'parent'

Tags: php, arrays

I am sorry if my title is incorrect, was not sure what these array values are called.

I am doing an api call that returns data, i want to use that data. 
Now in the data it is possible to have up to 20 'offers'. 
Each has their own price.
I would like to return the lowest price

The structure of the results are
results -> 0 -> offers -> "number from 0-19" -> price
So each offer (with number 0-19) will have a price.

Is there an easy way to grab all of that data at once and just output the lowest price?

```
$price = $price_array['results'][0]['offers']['*can i cycle this part*']['price'];
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Could "cycle this part" be solved through a simple, but really common `foreach`?

Comment: Do : `$minPrice = min(array_column($price_array['results'][0]['offers'],'price'));echo $minPrice;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach ($price_array['results'][0]['offers'] as $offer) {
    echo $offer['price'];
    // and do what you want
}
```

Or maybe:

```
$minPrice = min(array_column($price_array['results'][0]['offers'], 'price'));
echo $minPrice;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use array_column and min().

```
$price = min(array_column($price_array['results'][0]['offers'],'price'));
```

This will return the lowest price in that column of the array.